# How to pick latest CSV file in python?

Tags: python

I have many files in a folder. Like:

```
tb_exec_ns_decile_20190129.csv
tb_exec_ns_decile_20190229.csv
tb_exec_ns_decile_20190329.csv
```

So i just want to pick latest file:

```
tb_exec_ns_decile_20190329.csv
```

Comment: It depends on how you defining your `latest`, just the filename's time or the acutal file creating time.

Answer (score 4):

```
import glob
import os

latest_csv = max(glob.glob('/path/to/folder/*.csv'), key=os.path.getctime) #give path to your desired file path
print latest_csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your csv files share a common prefix, you can
simply use `max` on the list of files. Assuming you are located
in the directory with your files and `tb_exec_ns_decile_20190329.csv`
has the latest date:

```
>>> import glob
>>> max(glob.glob('tb_exec_ns_decile_*.csv'))
'tb_exec_ns_decile_20190329.csv'
```